# Difficulty with unusual many to many select query

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many, select-query

I've just started to learn MySQL.  I've been researching this for a few hours, unfortunately I can't find a solution.  I suspect this is pretty easy, I just don't know how to do it.  I haven't been able to find a similar situation here or on other sites.

Here is some example data

```
computer
+------------------+
idcomputer | name
1          | komp001
2          | komp002 

computer_has_software
+---------------------------------------+
computer_idcomputer | software_idsoftware
1                   | 1
1                   | 2

software
+------------------+
idsoftware | name
1          | notepad
2          | eclipse
3          | firefox
4          | google chrome
```

As you can see `komp001` has both notepad and eclipse installed.

I want a query that will tell me what software is available, but not installed on `komp001` - i.e. all software not on `komp001`.

I would expect the answer to be firefox and google chrome.

```
software
+------------------------+
idsoftware | name
3          | firefox
4          | google chrome
```

Comment: are you want do to SELECT query by idcomputer or name (komp001)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2914a/3

```
SELECT
s.*
FROM 
  software as s
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT
     *
   FROM
     computer_has_software
   WHERE
     computer_idcomputer = 1
  ) as chs
ON 
  s.idsoftware = chs.software_idsoftware
WHERE
  chs.software_idsoftware IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.  You can use a `CROSS JOIN` to get all entries from the software table, then do a `LEFT JOIN` to the computer_has_software table `WHERE` software_idsoftware `IS NULL` to get software that does not exist for that computer.

```
SELECT  s.idsoftware, s.name

FROM    computer as c

        CROSS JOIN software as s

        LEFT JOIN computer_has_software as chs 
        ON s.idsoftware = chs.software_idsoftware
        AND c.idcomputer = chs.computer_idcomputer

WHERE   chs.software_idsoftware IS NULL
        and c.name = 'komp001';
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2914a/9)

Comment: You are correct.  I figured I would include it just in case there were additional fields or where conditions that he might need to pull that were not in his example.